# Error while printing a string at the console

Tags: python

```
for i in table.keys():
if table[i]==18798965:
    first=i
if table[i]==12738624:
    second=i
>>> print ("the encyrpted word is: %s%s") %(first,second);

the encyrpted word is: %s%s
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#31>", line 1, in <module>
print ("the encyrpted word is: %s%s") %(first,second);
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'
```

I think that the version of python at university is different than the one i'm using at home.

Can anybody help me with this error?

Comment: -1 for URGENT PLEASE LOOK

Comment: "URGENT PLEASE CLOSE" you said? Wokay.

Comment: This is a new user.  Don't be so harsh.  They need coaching, not rejection.

Comment: `print("The encrypted word is: {18798965}{12738624}".format(**table))`

Comment: Voted to reopen.  This is not too localized as it deals with making print statement a function in Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

`%` the way you're using it operates on strings; you're trying to operate on the value returned by `print()`, which is `None`.

Move the formatting inside the `()`:

```
print ("the encyrpted word is: %s%s" %(first,second))
```

n.b.: Python doesn't use `;` at the end of lines of code.

Comment: And the university Python works most likely because it's 2.7 or so, where `print` was just a keyword, so `("test")` was just a parenthised expression and you could use `%`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies, i ammended the code correctly.

Apologies if i offended anyone with my 'urgency'. The code was working on an earlier version of Python. I got home ready to submit my assignment and it didn't work. It's due in 3 hours :)

Thanks again.